# eks worker node public ip assignment

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

With the instruction https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/worker.html it is possible to bring up Kube cluster worker nodes. I wanted the worker node not to have public ip. I don't see Amazon gives me that option as when running the cloudformation script. How can I have option not to have public ip on worker nodes

Answer (score 1):

You would normally set this up ahead of time in the Subnet rather than doing it per machine. You can set `Auto-assign public IPv4 address` to false in the subnets you are using the for the worker instances.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just checked the configuration Auto-assign public IPv4 is set to "no" . I was under impression that something we can do in the cloud formation .

Comment: What you see is what you get. You can copy Amazon's cloudformation template and make your own modifications to it, but it's not something they exposed.

Comment: Yep, I was looking at the file https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2018-11-07/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml and also at https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml . I did see a line      NodeLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'   I am still trying to figure out the dependency to this file

Comment: Yup , I Worked by changing the script and uploading it in S3

Comment: Ahh, if they specifically set it to true, that also explains why setting it at the subnet level didn’t work too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this behaviour inside your group node template (Cloudformation template).

- You have to download your group node template (ex https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-02-11/amazon-eks-nodegroup.yaml)
- Edit yaml file replacing the atribbute **AssociatePublicIpAddress** to false.

> ```
>   NodeLaunchConfig:
>     Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
>     Properties:
>       AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
> ```

- Update your  stack (https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation) using the edited file.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020/03/09, this is not possible.

See [this thread](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/607).